# How resource management work in snappy?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-core, resource-limiting

If I deploy a software with snappy how does the resource management occurs for that particular software? Is the resources elastic in terms of the system? Or is it defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're "elastic", snaps aren't resource-controlled like containerized (docker or lxd) applications are. Snapped applications will use machine resources as any other local program would.